# How to implement *Remember me* option using Amazon Cognito sdk?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement a *Remember Me* option for authentication workflow using *amazon-cognito-identity-js* in Angular2 project. [Issue reference](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cognito-angular2-quickstart/issues/119).

**Current authentication flow**

1. If *Remember me* option is checked then save token and JWT token(specially do this because I need some other user info such as groups and roles) to cookie with expiration date. (ex : 5 days )
2. Auth guard (that is checking all routing changes even if root routing) will check token(not JWT) first
3. If cookie is empty then redirect to Login page.
4. If cookie exists then check session(using function of sdk), session is invalid then redirect to Login page.
5. If session is valid then update JWT(not token) and guard returns true.

I think it seems fine, but I am getting some unexpected errors, not often but once 1 hour has passed (actual session expired).

**Questions**

1. Do I have to update token as well? At `step 5`.
2. Is `this.cognitoUtil.getCurrentUser();` asynchronous function?
3. What will be returned from `cognitoUser.getSession()` if session is expired?
4. If *Ques 3* returns session (even if it is valid or invalid), what is the returning value of `session.isValid()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes. I mean I don't know what you mean by token & JWT token. In terms of Cognito tokens, there are id, access & refresh tokens. Id & access tokens expire in an hour & refresh token in 30 days (default). See [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html) doc for reference.
2. I don't think so. I mean *amazon-cognito-identity-js*  SDK uses normal javascript SDKs and there [getCurrentUser()](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/3e6cb695d9271c8333b6da4b01e52a375de2a329/src/CognitoUserPool.js#L116) just retrieves user from local storage.
3. The SDKs will automatically try to refresh the id/access token using the refresh token (which is valid for 30 days by default).
4. Returns boolean. See [this](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/3e6cb695d9271c8333b6da4b01e52a375de2a329/src/CognitoUserSession.js#L81) SDK definition.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

Cognito provides configuration for remembering devices from which user login.

You can find this configuration under devices menu in your user pool settings.

[image: remember me setup cognito]

Basically three options are provided with question *"Do you want to remember your user's devices?"*

1. Always  - Cognito will always remember devices.
2. User Opt In - Depends on user choice.
3. NO - Never tracks devices.

For more details please visit this link - Here you will find implementation for the same. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/tracking-and-remembering-devices-using-amazon-cognito-your-user-pools/

Comment: Isn't it a specific solution for MFA?

Comment: @vahdet do you have an update?

Comment: Remember devices is for MFA only, Krishna is wrong here.  
to implement remeber me you would have to track access and refresh tokens on the backend and keep smartly refreshing the token while remember me cookie is set. ive implemented this process before